# Powershell copy a View from database and insert to existing Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I got a View, and a List of Sharepoint with same more of column. In Powershell at every Time Job I wan't add only this records, which are new, and add them to a list. Did You know any of scripts which can update from powershell to a View.

Comment: You got a view and a list and you want to  update a view? Or do you want to show in a view only new documents?

Comment: I have got a SQL View, and I want to connect them with Sharepoint list, which will have another six columns. And when a record will be adding to the view I must add a free new record to Sharepoint list, and remember a records wchich was aded before with a Likes and 6 Columns wchich can be written before update.